# mysql distinct not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to avoid picking any two of the same categories or entries using my code below...

Its working well but very occasionally it displays duplicate categories...

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    exp_categories.cat_id, exp_categories.cat_name, exp_categories.cat_url_title
      ,exp_category_posts.entry_id, exp_channel_titles.status 
    FROM (exp_categories 
    LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts 
           ON exp_categories.cat_id = exp_category_posts.cat_id) 
    LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles 
           ON exp_category_posts.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
    WHERE exp_categories.group_id = 2 
      AND exp_category_posts.entry_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND exp_channel_titles.status = 'open' 
    GROUP BY exp_categories.cat_id
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Are you positive that all the columns show the same values when the categories are shown multible times?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Can you describe in simple words what do you want your query to show?

Comment: mmmm ill check and come back in two secs

Comment: I want to show individual posts from multiple categories.  But the category should never be the same and neither should the entry so they're always unique

So two seperate categories with two completely different entries (because entries can be associated with more than one category sometimes)

Comment: depend of your needs `SELECT DISTINCT(column)` may help you to filter by one column.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is supposed to show you distinct rows, that is distinct combinations of all columns.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. For what I can tell by your description int he comments to the question, you may want to look into `group by` instead or remove the category from the select list.

Comment: The trouble is i need the category ID to send to the page to get the correct project...

Comment: I ask this because there is already a groupby in there...so i'm not sure what you're describing

Comment: `select distinct(columnA)`, and then also group by that same field `GROUP BY columnA`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need outer JOINS here, since your condition `exp_channel_titles.status = 'open'` will never be true for NULLs in the right part of the JOINS.

```
SELECT
    c.cat_id,
    c.cat_name,
    c.cat_url_title,
    cp.entry_id,
    ct.status 
FROM exp_categories c
JOIN exp_category_posts cp 
   ON c.cat_id = cp.cat_id 
JOIN exp_channel_titles ct 
   ON cp.entry_id = ct.entry_id 
WHERE c.group_id = 2 
  AND ct.status = 'open' 
GROUP BY c.cat_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 2
```

Wihout grouping by cat_id, the query will obviously result in duplicate categories for different entry_id. Grouping should eliminate this, though the expected result is not clear to me.

Comment: The distinct value i remember now - i put that in there to stop entries coming back with no data

Comment: @andy, I am sorry, I do not understand your comment =)